# Stop UV's Rotating when unwrapped

Tags: mesh, uv, edit-mode

I am trying to unwrap faces which are all exactly the same size. Some have slices through them, but that shouldn't matter should it?

I am trying to unwrap them to then overlap every single one so that I can make them share the same texture, however when I unwrap them they are all unwrapping at different rotations.

It's making it a pain to unwrap as it find it impossible and tedious to find out which direction the whole squares are facing.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s9uk.jpg

Comment: Include images into the question body please. Ngons are always bad to unwrap and will provide you with unexpected result on the uv map. Aside from that why unwrapping this into individual squares, any special reason?UV map will be more predictable and easy to work with if done as one or several islands. When you have so many of them it's really hard to make use of texturing without just painting on the mesh.

Comment: Hey Zak,

I want to overlap them so i can use one texture in Substance Painter to repeat it all over tower.

There isn't any Ngons in this though, they are all squares.

Comment: As I see there are Ngons below and above windows because of 2 additional cuts for the window. Though general principle is the same - UV map is often done into one single island as already shown in the answer and texturing on that in any program you like

Comment: The slabs underneath the windows are a shape on their own, there is no Ngons.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a single seam down the length of the silo (marked in red) and then do a normal UV unwrap. This way the UV layout is connected, and the texture space is used a lot more efficiently.

[image]

Generally speaking using overlapping UV is considered bad practice in Substance Painter, because it prevents Painter from baking proper AO maps and the results is generally very unpredictable.

Comment: Hey Mike, this is what I originally did as it made most sense. However because the tower is so huge the quality of the texture didn’t look to great. Trying to use as less materials as possible for batching issues.